# airflow dynamic task returns list instead of dictionary

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer, airflow-2.x

Please refer my code below.

While `recon_rule_setup` task is running, each time it is getting Dictionary (`recon_conf`) as input from previous `read_recon_config` task.

However, while `recon_rule_exec` is running, it is getting List as input (`recon_rule`) from previous task.

My expectation was, `recon_rule_setup` should run 2 times and `recon_rule_exec` should run 4 times depending on the return values.

Why expand is behaving differently each time.

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.models import DAG, XCom
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.decorators import task
from airflow.utils.db import provide_session
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.task_group import TaskGroup


@provide_session
def clear_xcom_data(session=None, **kwargs):
    dag_instance = kwargs["dag"]
    dag_id = dag_instance._dag_id
    session.query(XCom).filter(XCom.dag_id == dag_id).delete()


@task(task_id="read_recon_config")
def read_recon_config(dag_run=None):
    parent_dict = dag_run.conf
    d1 = {"name": "Santanu"}
    d2 = {"name": "Ghosh"}
    return [d1, d2]


@task(task_id="recon_rule_setup")
def recon_rule_setup(recon_conf):
    print(f"type of recon_conf_dict: {type(recon_conf)}")
    print(f"recon_conf_dict: {recon_conf}")
    return [recon_conf, {"name": "Kolkata"}]


@task(task_id="recon_rule_exec")
def recon_rule_exec(recon_rule, master_key):
    print(f"master_key type: {type(master_key)}")
    print(f"master_key: {master_key}")
    print(f"recon_rule type: {type(recon_rule)}")
    print(f"recon_rule: {recon_rule}")


default_args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    'start_date': days_ago(1),
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1
}

dag_name_id = "dynamic_demo"
cur_datetime = datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f")[:-3]
master_dag_key = f"{dag_name_id}_{cur_datetime}"

with DAG(
        dag_id=dag_name_id,
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval=None,
        catchup=False
) as dag:

    start = BashOperator(task_id="start", bash_command='echo "starting reconciliation"', do_xcom_push=False)
    stop = BashOperator(task_id="stop", bash_command='echo "stopping reconciliation"', do_xcom_push=False)

    delete_xcom = PythonOperator(
        task_id="delete_xcom",
        python_callable=clear_xcom_data
    )

    with TaskGroup(group_id="reconciliation_process") as tg1:
        recon_config_list = read_recon_config()
        recon_rule_list = recon_rule_setup.expand(recon_conf=recon_config_list)
        recon_rule_exec.partial(master_key=master_dag_key).expand(recon_rule=recon_rule_list)

    start >> tg1 >> delete_xcom >> stop
```

Regards,
Santanu

Comment: Hi @Santanu Ghosh, If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to return the dictionary as a list that’s why it is returning the dictionary inside a list. For your requirement, you can try the below code which is returning a dictionary.

**Code:**

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.models import DAG, XCom
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.decorators import task
from airflow.utils.db import provide_session
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.task_group import TaskGroup


@provide_session
def clear_xcom_data(session=None, **kwargs):
    dag_instance = kwargs["dag"]
    dag_id = dag_instance._dag_id
    session.query(XCom).filter(XCom.dag_id == dag_id).delete()


@task(task_id="read_recon_config")
def read_recon_config(dag_run=None):
    parent_dict = dag_run.conf
    d1 = {1:{"name": "S"} ,2:{"name": "G"}}
    
    return d1


@task(task_id="recon_rule_setup")
def recon_rule_setup(recon_conf):
    print(f"type of recon_conf_dict: {type(recon_conf)}")
    print(f"recon_conf_dict: {recon_conf}")
    return [recon_conf, {"name": "Kolkata"}]


@task(task_id="recon_rule_exec")
def recon_rule_exec(recon_rule, master_key):
    print(f"master_key type: {type(master_key)}")
    print(f"master_key: {master_key}")
    print(f"recon_rule type: {type(recon_rule)}")
    print(f"recon_rule: {recon_rule}")


default_args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    'start_date': days_ago(1),
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1
}

dag_name_id = "dynamic_demo"
cur_datetime = datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f")[:-3]
master_dag_key = f"{dag_name_id}_{cur_datetime}"

with DAG(
        dag_id=dag_name_id,
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval=None,
        catchup=False
) as dag:

    start = BashOperator(task_id="start", bash_command='echo "starting reconciliation"', do_xcom_push=False)
    stop = BashOperator(task_id="stop", bash_command='echo "stopping reconciliation"', do_xcom_push=False)
    
    delete_xcom = PythonOperator(
        task_id="delete_xcom",
        python_callable=clear_xcom_data
    )
   

    with TaskGroup(group_id="reconciliation_process") as tg1:
        recon_config_list = read_recon_config()
        recon_rule_list = recon_rule_setup.expand(recon_conf=recon_config_list)
        recon_rule_exec.partial(master_key=master_dag_key).expand(recon_rule=recon_rule_list)

    start >> tg1 >> delete_xcom >> stop
```

**Output:**

[image]